# Java Swing move JTextField values into second button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

Perhaps this was already asked once but I am kinda stuck and cant find a solution by myself.
I got text from first button using text fields. And now i need to get this text into second button OR text file.

Code below and i know that this one gives error.

```
System.out.println("Author's name: " + newauthor());
System.out.println("Book name: " + newbook());
```

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class library extends JFrame 
{

private JPanel pnl;

public library() throws FileNotFoundException {

    pnl = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton addbutton = new JButton("Add new book");
    addbutton.setBounds(75, 30, 150, 30);
    addbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            JTextField authorfield = new JTextField(15);
            JTextField bookField = new JTextField(15);
            JPanel mypanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            mypanel.add(new JLabel("Type Author's Name and Book name:"));
            mypanel.add(new JLabel("Author's Name:"));
            mypanel.add(authorfield);
            mypanel.add(new JLabel("Book name:"));
            mypanel.add(bookField);


            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, mypanel, 
            "Add a new book", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
                {
                String newauthor = authorfield.getText();
                String newbook = bookField.getText();
                if (!newauthor.isEmpty() && !newbook.isEmpty()) 
                        {       
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pnl, "Book "+bookField.getText()+"\nAuthor "+authorfield.getText()+"\nSuccessfully added to the list.",
                                "Book was added.", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


                        }
                else    
                        {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pnl, "Both must be filled!",
                                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                }
       }                
    });
    panel.add(addbutton);


    JButton listbutton = new JButton("List");
    listbutton.setBounds(75, 60, 150, 30);
    panel.add(listbutton);
    addbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {

                        System.out.println("Author's name: " + newauthor());
                        System.out.println("Book name: " + newbook());
                }
        });
       JButton deletebutton = new JButton("Delete");
       deletebutton.setBounds(75, 90, 150, 30);
       panel.add(deletebutton);



       setTitle("Library Menu");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
           library ex = new library();
           ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"..need to get this text into second button OR text file."*  Those are two *very different* requirements!  You should really decide upon one or the other for this question, else I think it is 'too broad' for SO.

Comment: For now i need to get it into second button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is having many issues.

1.Both should be declared inside of your class but outside of your any method.

```
String newauthor = "";
String newbook = "";
```

Now in the `if` condition

```
         if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
                {
                newauthor = authorfield.getText();
                newbook = bookField.getText();
                ..............................
```

2.

```
JButton listbutton = new JButton("List");
listbutton.setBounds(75, 60, 150, 30);
panel.add(listbutton);
listbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()// its listbutton not addbutton
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
            {

                    System.out.println("Author's name: " + newauthor);
                    System.out.println("Book name: " + newbook);
            }
    });
```

Both `newauthor` and `newbook` are variables. But not methods.

Comment: Thank you. My bad about addbutton. Code kinda works but gives me blank now. I need text from addbutton into listbutton.

Comment: just follow the above 2 steps. Its will prints @JustNick

Comment: No you are missing something just check it. But with above answer surely you will get OP. @JustNick

Comment: Seems like i missed last edit. It works now. Thank you. Issue was indeed in if.